# ORDER BY id IN Subquery

Tags: sql, select, join, subquery, sql-order-by

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT i.* 
FROM items i 
WHERE i.id 
IN (
    SELECT c.item_id 
    FROM cart c 
    WHERE c.sessID=MY_SESSION_ID
   )
```

It's working beautifully, but I need to sort items from the cart by date of purchase (cart.id) DESC. 
I don't want sort in PHP. How can I sort by cart.id?

I tried:

```
SELECT i.* 
FROM items i 
WHERE i.id 
IN (
    SELECT c.item_id 
    FROM cart c 
    WHERE c.sessID=MY_SESSION_ID
   ) 
ORDER BY c.id
```

But it did not sort correctly.

Comment: Why don't you sort on `I.ID` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT i.* FROM items i LEFT OUTER JOIN cart c 
ON i.id = c.item_id WHERE c.sessID=MY_SESSION_ID AND 
c.item_id is not null ORDER BY c.id
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your **Sub query** to `Inner Join`. `Sub query` will not allow to you refer the columns outside of `sub query`. So change it to `Inner join`

```
SELECT i.*
FROM   items i
       JOIN (SELECT item_id,
                    id
             FROM   cart) C
         ON i.id = c.item_id
            AND c.sessID = MY_SESSION_ID
ORDER  BY c.id Desc
```

or use this.

```
SELECT i.*
FROM   items i
       JOIN cart C
         ON i.id = c.item_id
            AND c.sessID = MY_SESSION_ID
ORDER  BY c.id Desc
```

Comment: You have to pass this condition in subquery **c.sessID = MY_SESSION_ID**

Comment: @SaharshShah - Not needed. I have joined it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT i.* 
FROM items i 
INNER JOIN cart c ON i.id = c.item_id 
WHERE c.sessID = MY_SESSION_ID 
GROUP BY i.id 
ORDER BY MAX(c.id) DESC;
```

**OR**

```
SELECT i.* 
FROM items i 
INNER JOIN (SELECT item_id, MAX(id) AS cid 
            FROM cart 
            WHERE sessID = MY_SESSION_ID 
            GROUP BY item_id
          ) AS c ON i.id = c.item_id 
ORDER BY c.cid DESC;
```